# How can I filter Amazon.com results to exclude 3rd party merchants?

Tags: amazon, google-chrome-extensions, userscripts, firefox-extensions

I'd like to search Amazon.com for products that Amazon sells without having to see all the third party merchants products.  I've tried using some userscripts and some chrome extensions that claim to do the job but none of them seem to work.  I prefer Chrome, but I can use FF for the searches if someone knows of a FF fix that actually works.

Comment: posting a non-webapp solution is perfectly fine. See [this](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-it-accepted-to-answer-questions-with-non-web-based-solutions) for more info.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>[Amazon Advanced Search Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ccepjmcefeeoaddlbgmjhpcacpemceop)</strike>

[Amazon Prime Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdjedjdjdlblhcbpecnnddahnonblajk)

Comment: This link now gives 'An error occurred: Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author.'

Comment: @ClareMacrae Yes, that extension appears to be dead now. I added another one that accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to add `&emi=ATVPDKIKX0DER` to the end of the URL for your search.  Just perform your search, then click in the address bar and paste that at the end and hit enter and you'll get only items sold by Amazon.

If you want a shortcut to do this, add a new bookmark in your browser. For the name enter whatever you want, and for the URL enter:

```
javascript:(function() { window.location.href += '&emi=ATVPDKIKX0DER' })()
```

(A dynamic bookmark like this is known as a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).) Now after you perform a search, simply select that bookmark and it will reload the search automatically but only show items sold by Amazon.

Tip: many browsers have a bookmarks bar or configurable shortcuts for bookmarks that may be used to make it faster to use the bookmarklet.

Note that as of 2023 sometime, this doesn't work the same as before. You have to select a category such as from the search drop-down or after searching and then run this. What I like to do to cast the broadest net is to search for something, click the category I think is most relevant to it out of the choices, and then right in that same area click the topmost category one level below "all" and then run this. Running this in a search of the "all" category does alter the mix of results returned but it doesn't seem to have any rhyme or reason that I can tell.

Comment: Note that the "emi" varies by region, the one given here is for the US, https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonprime/comments/13nyl2k/amazon_no_longer_offers_the_option_to_filter/ has some values for other regions. I successfully tested that A3P5ROKL5A1OLE works for amazon UK.

Answer (score 2):

If you sign in with your account and search for a product there is an option on the left where the search filters are called "seller" Amazon is the first option.

Comment: I only have the option to filter by "Department", "Shipping" and "Brand" in the left hand column.

Comment: You have to select a department first.

Comment: Unfortunately the seller selection no longer appears consistently on the search results page even with a department selected

Answer (score 2):

Most filtering methods for getting stuff that's "Sold by Amazon" stopped working, even when clicking on one of the store departments (which used to work). Luckily for us, there's still a way that works (although why they made the nice clickable toggle disappear beats me).

Anyhoo the way I've found to make it work is to paste this at the end of your the web page address at the top of your screen:
`&rh=p_n_enc-merchantbin%3AATVPDKIKX0DER` instead of `emi=ATVPDKIKX0DER`. As somebody said, this only works for amazon.com. For amazon.co.uk the code is A3P5ROKL5A1OLE. I've also found codes for amazon.ca (A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB), amazon.de (A3JWKAKR8XB7XF), amazon.fr (A1X6FK5RDHNB96) and amazon.co.jp (AN1VRQENFRJN5).

Pay attention to the text that goes before the code for each Amazon country: `&rh=p_n_enc-merchantbin%3A`.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if there is already a `&rh=` in the address bar, you'll need to combine the `p_n_enc-merchantbin%3A` with whatever else is there by adding a `%7C` in between (you can see this be done for other combinations of search filters).

It would be really nice if somebody could make this into a Chrome/Firefox extension!